# IDEA doesn't see maven dependencies

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I renamed the folder with my project and re-imported it in Idea. Although Idea recognizes it as maven project and all needed dependencies are avail in pom, Idea doesn't understand them: f.e. I add @Test in code, Idea cannot import it. What the heck?

I also deleted .Idea files and re-imported. The same thing happened.

Auto import is enabled in Settings->Maven
Can you please help me? Thanks.

Update:

It was because of the `<scope>test</scope>` in pom, but why? Before folder renaming it was cool.

Comment: What about doing a File | Invalidate Caches/Restart?

Comment: `@Test` is either from JUnit or TestNG (or perhaps something similar) which is correctly scoped as a test dependency and will be included only in the test classpath, hence IJ will be able to import it only in test classes which are located under `src/test/java/...`. Where is your class physically located? If it was created under `src/main/java/...` then it's only normal for IJ to complain, and it should be moved to the test package. Also under `File -> Project structure -> Modules` on the Sources tab, ensure that the directories are correctly marked as *Source folder* and *Test source folder*